# Mi JS no recorre un Json

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

Tengo que desarrollar un proyecto, tipo carrito de compras, mi js debería recorrer un json, que en este caso está dentro de otro archivo .js, la cuestión es que no lo toma, retorna indefinido, he movido todo y el problema persiste.
**Este es el js:**

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    const productContainer = document.getElementById("mercaderia");
  
        products.forEach(function(product){
        if(product.avaliable){
                const cardProduct = buildProductCard(product);
                productContainer.innerHTML += cardProduct;
            }

        })
})
```

**Este el html donde debe crear:**

```
    <script defer src="js/domBuilder.js"></script>
    <script defer src="js/info.js"></script>
    <script defer src="js/main.js"></script>
    <title>ElColdoCocina</title>    
</head>
<body>

    <!-- NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ElColdoCocina<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
          
        </ul>
        </div> 
    </nav>
​
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="subtitulo">Nuestros Productos</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
​  
        <div id="mercaderia" class="row"></div>
    </div>


**Este la tarjeta que debe crear:**

    function buildProductCard(product){
    const htmlCard=
         `<div class="col-lg-4 mercaderia__card">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="${product.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="img">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${product.name}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">${product.description}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">${product.price}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;

            return htmlCard;
}
```

**Y este el json que debe recorrer:**

```
const products = [{
```

"id" : "AAA001",
"name" : "Pan de Jamon",
"description" : "Masa hojaldrada relleno de jamon ahumado, panceta ahumada, aceituna y uvas pasas",
"img" : "image/pandejamon.jpg",
"price" : 700,
"available" : true,
tags : ["pan", "jamon", "panceta"]
},{
"id" : "BBB002",
"name" : "Tequeños",
"description" : "Masa semi-hojaldrada rellena de queso venezolano, con salsa para dipear",
"img" : "image/tequeño.jpg",
"price" : 30,
"available" : true,
tags : ["tequeño", "queso"]
},{
"id" : "CCC003",
"name" : "Pan de Guayaba",
"description" : "Pan de masa suave, relleno de dulce de guayaba y queso venezolano",
"img" : "image/panguayaba.jpg",
"price" : 600,
"available" : true,
tags : ["pan", "guayaba", "queso"]
}];

Agradecería cualquier ayuda! Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Y cómo obtienes el JSON Desde tu JS?

Comment: Con el forEach del js le paso por parámetro el JSON. Todos estan linkeados en e HTML.

Comment: ¿Le pasas el JSON como string, verdad?

Comment: Si, es decir que habria que convertirlo con el json.stringify?

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que le pasas el JSON como string, al pasarle el JSON como string la cosa varía, ya que necesitarás usar `JSON.parse()`, este método convierte un JSON en string a un objeto o array

Y el método `JSON.stringify()` convierte un JSON a un string

De manera que tenemos:

```js
const products = '[{"id" : "AAA001", "name" : "Pan de Jamon", "description" : "Masa hojaldrada relleno de jamon ahumado, panceta ahumada, aceituna y uvas pasas", "img" : "image/pandejamon.jpg", "price" : 700, "available" : true, "tags" : ["pan", "jamon", "panceta"] },{ "id" : "BBB002", "name" : "Tequeños", "description" : "Masa semi-hojaldrada rellena de queso venezolano, con salsa para dipear", "img" : "image/tequeño.jpg", "price" : 30, "available" : true, "tags" : ["tequeño", "queso"] },{ "id" : "CCC003", "name" : "Pan de Guayaba", "description" : "Pan de masa suave, relleno de dulce de guayaba y queso venezolano", "img" : "image/panguayaba.jpg", "price" : 600, "available" : true, "tags" : ["pan", "guayaba", "queso"] }]';

const productContainer = document.getElementById("mercaderia");
    productsJSON = JSON.parse(products)
    productsJSON.forEach(function(product){
      const htmlCard=
         `<div class="col-lg-4 mercaderia__card">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="${product.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="img">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${product.name}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">${product.description}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">${product.price}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
            document.write(htmlCard)
})
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ElColdoCocina<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
          
        </ul>
        </div> 
    </nav>
​
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="subtitulo">Nuestros Productos</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
​  
        <div id="mercaderia" class="row"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Todo el JSON esta en otro archivo js, todos linkeados en el html y en js con variables globales, y aún así no muestra. Gracias por tu respuesta!!